# function timed out after 5000 milliseconds - Angular 4 - Protractor & cucumber

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am automating an angular 4 application with protractor & cucumber framework.

Getting error for a simple button click. (Not all the times)

```
1) Scenario: Scenario 2 - features\Home.feature:9
   Step: Then Click on edit button - features\Home.feature:11
   Step Definition: stepDefinitions\FirstStep.ts:31
   Message:
     Error: function timed out after 5000 milliseconds
       at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\MyWorkspace\protractor-cucumber-final\protractor-cucumber-final\node_modules\cucumber\lib\user_code_runner.js:91:22)
       at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

[Checked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254392/message-function-timed-out-after-5000-milliseconds-protractor-cucumberjs) I believe no need to set wait times as protractor is intelligent enough to resolve promises

my project details as follows:

Node: v6.10.3
protractor: v5.1.2

**StepDefinition.ts:**

```
let homePage = new HomePage();

Then(/^Click on edit button$/, async () => {
   await homePage.clickEditButton();
});
```

**HomePage.ts:**

```
async clickEditButton() {
    console.log('clicking on Edit Button');
    await this.editButton.click();
}
```

**package.json** (part of it)

```
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
 "test": "protractor config/config.js",
 "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
 "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
"dependencies": {
  "chai": "^4.0.2",
  "cucumber": "^2.3.0",
  "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
  "protractor": "^5.1.1",
  "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^3.1.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
  "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
  "cucumber-html-report": "^0.6.0",
  "cucumber-html-reporter": "^0.5.2",
  "cucumberjs-allure-reporter": "^1.0.3",
  "pg": "^6.0.3"
 }
```

**config.js**

```
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200/",
  framework: "custom",
  frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
  specs: ["../features/*.feature"],
  exclude: "../features/database.feature",
  resultJsonOutputFile: "./reports/json/protractor_report.json",
  onPrepare: function() {
      // browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      browser.manage().window().maximize();
      global.expect = chai.expect;
    },
  cucumberOpts: {
      strict: true,
      format: ["pretty"],
      require: ["../stepDefinitions/*.js", "../support/*.js"],
      tags: "@micro" 
    }
 };
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATED 28-Aug'17:**

***ManageRecipeStep.ts***

```
import {defineSupportCode} from 'cucumber';
import {ManageRecipePage} from "../pages/ManageRecipePage";
var chai = require("chai");
var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
let expect = chai.expect;

Then(/^Cancel button should be displayed$/, async () => { 
 await expect(manageRecipePage.getCancelButton()).to.eventually.equal('Cancel');
});
```

***ManageRecipePage.ts***

```
 import {ActionUtil} from "../utils/ActionUtil";
 import {BasePage, IdentificationType} from "../utils/BasePage";

 const Locators = {
    cancelByText: {
      type:IdentificationType[IdentificationType.PartialButtonText],
      value: "Cancel"
      }
 };
 let actionUtil = new ActionUtil();

 export class ManageRecipePage extends BasePage {
   async getCancelButton() {
    await actionUtil.getElementText(Locators.cancelByText);
   }
 }
```

***ActionUtil.ts***

```
 import {BasePage} from "./BasePage";

 export class ActionUtil {
   private basePage: BasePage = new BasePage();

   async getElementText(obj) {
    let attempts = 0;

    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
            return await this.basePage.ElementLocator(obj).getText();
        } catch(StaleElementException) {
            console.log("EXCEPTION while getting Text" + StaleElementException);
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    return null; // todo: this case
 }
```

***BasePage.ts***

```
import { browser, element, by, protractor, $$, $ } from 'protractor';

export enum IdentificationType {
Xpath,
Css,
Id,
Js,
Name,
PartialLinkText,
ClassName,
PartialButtonText
}

export class BasePage {

 ElementLocator(obj) {
    switch (obj.type) {
        case IdentificationType[IdentificationType.Xpath]:
            return element(by.xpath(obj.value));
        case IdentificationType[IdentificationType.ClassName]:
            return element(by.className(obj.value));
        case IdentificationType[IdentificationType.Id]:
            return element(by.id(obj.value));
        case IdentificationType[IdentificationType.Js]:
            return element(by.js(obj.value));
        case IdentificationType[IdentificationType.Css]:
            return element(by.css(obj.value));
        case IdentificationType[IdentificationType.PartialButtonText]:
            return element(by.partialButtonText(obj.value));
        default:
            break;
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default timeout for cucumber is 5 sec. [Setting default time](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/api_reference.md) (to 10 sec) worked for me. [Example is here](https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript/blob/master/support/hooks.ts). This issue might be because application is down.

@quirimmo Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

For me, (I am not using async/await), I am using

```
 SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: true,
```

in protractor.conf.js

In my hooks.ts, I need either one of these:

```
    BeforeAll({ timeout: 60 * 1000 }, () => {
      setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
      return browser.get(config.baseUrl);
    });


    BeforeAll({ timeout: 60 * 1000 }, () => {
      defineSupportCode( ({ setDefaultTimeout }) => {
        setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);
      });
      return browser.get(config.baseUrl);
    });
```

Here is my import:

```
   import { Before, After, BeforeAll, defineSupportCode, Status, setDefaultTimeout } from 'cucumber';
```

Comment: Where should the hooks.ts file go? Is it simply a case of requiring the file in the cucumberOpts?

Comment: Just added it to my require array and it found it

Comment: setDefaultTimeout in BeforeAll solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) Be sure to disable the `WebDriver Control Flow` when using protractor with `async/await` through the following command in the config:

```
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false
```

Here the spec of the property from the official doc:

> Enable/disable the WebDriver Control Flow.
>   WebDriverJS (and by extention, Protractor) uses a Control Flow to
>   manage the order in which commands are executed and promises are
>   resolved (see docs/control-flow.md for details).
>   However, as syntax like `async`/`await` are being introduced, WebDriverJS has
>   decided to deprecate the control flow, and have users manage the
>   asynchronous activity themselves (details here:
>   https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969).
>   At the moment, the WebDriver Control Flow is still enabled by default. You
>   can disable it by setting the environment variable
>   `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` to `0`.  In a webdriver release in Q4
>   2017, the Control Flow will be disabled by default, but you will be
>   able to re-enable it by setting `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` to
>   `1`.  At a later point, the control flow will be removed for
>   good. If you don't like managing environment variables, you
>   can set this option in your config file, and Protractor will
>   handle enabling/disabling the control flow for you.  Setting this
>   option is higher priority than the `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER`
>   environment variable.
>   @type {boolean=}

2) Are you sure that Node 6.10.3 supports `async/await`? I remember that the official default support for `async/await` is since Node 7.6

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [archived in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153004/discussion-on-answer-by-quirimmo-function-timed-out-after-5000-milliseconds-an).